# How do i center array of button in ScrollView using SnapKit

Tags: swift, snapkit

How do i vertically center array of button of below in ScrollView using SnapKit.

```
for i in 0..<3 {

        itemCount = i

        let aButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

        aButton.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
        aButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        aButton.layer.cornerRadius = aButton.frame.size.width / 2
        aButton.clipsToBounds = true

        xCoord += buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons

        aScrollView.addSubview(aButton)

        aButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.center.equalTo(aScrollView)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish an array of buttons being equally spaced would be to use an UIStackView. This should work:

```
let buttonStackView = UIStackView()
buttonStackView.axis = .vertical
buttonStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
for i in 0..<3 {
    itemCount = i

    let aButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

    aButton.frame = CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
    aButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    aButton.layer.cornerRadius = aButton.frame.size.width / 2
    aButton.clipsToBounds = true

    xCoord += buttonWidth + gapBetweenButtons

    buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(aButton)

}
aScrollView.addSubview(buttonStackView)
buttonStackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
}
```

Comment: change to horizontal and got this http://imgur.com/a/q29pB  , i guess gapBetweenButtons is conflicting with stackview.distribution

Comment: @mclovin Set the stackview.spacing = gapBetweenButtons